# Is it possible to define a group of template parameters and specialize it conditionally

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

```
struct TypeA {
    using data_t = int;
    enum { thread_create = pthread_create }; // ???
};

struct TypeB {
    using data_t = double;
    enum { thread_create = another_kind_of_thread_create }; // ???
};

template<typename T>
class Test {
public:
    void func() {
        T::thread_create(); // ???
    }
private:
    T::data_t a;
};

Test<TypeA> t1;
Test<TypeB> t2;
```

What I'm trying to do is to specialize the template class `Test` with one single template parameter.

As you see, `data_t` shouldn't be any problem but it doesn't seem that passing a function is easy. This piece of code will generate an error: `error: enumerator value for 'thread_create' must have integral or unscoped enumeration type`.

Is it possible to pass a function like this?

Comment: `pthread_create` is a function, it makes little sense trying to stuff it into an enum. You could assign it to a function pointer, I suppose. Or you could have a static method that turns around and calls `pthread_create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I if understand you correctly, you want to switch thread creation function and data type depending on the specialization.
If so, why not sth like this?

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

void pthread_create(void*, void*);
void another_kind_of_thread_create(void*, void*);
//my fakes. use your includes here

struct TypeA {
    using data_t = int;
    using thread_create_t = void (*)(void*, void*);
    static constexpr thread_create_t  thread_create{pthread_create};
};

struct TypeB {
    using data_t = double;
    using thread_create_t = void (*)(void*, void*);
    static constexpr thread_create_t thread_create{another_kind_of_thread_create};
};

template<typename T>
class Test : public T {
public:
    void func() {
        T::thread_create(this, &a); //whatever, put here just to match the prototype...
    }
private:
    typename T::data_t a;
};

Test<TypeA> t1;
Test<TypeB> t2;

static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t1)::data_t, int>::value, "t1 should be int");
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(t2)::data_t, double>::value, "t2 should be double");
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Th37bn1n5)

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a pretty vanilla traits class. You are probably looking for something along these lines:

```
struct TypeA {
    using data_t = int;
    static void thread_create() { pthread_create() };
};
```

This would allow `T::thread_create();` syntax.